# I want to get text from an excel file with its font style and weight using C# .net?

Tags: c#, excel

While getting text from an excel its resetting the font style and its structure. I want to get that exact text as it shows in excel sheet. Like if I have a sentence in which some words are bold, I want to get that text as bold also.

Answer (score 0):

You should try EPPlus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/)
This is for creating excel workbooks, but I'm sure it has features for processing excel files as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess an alternative is to use the OpenXML SDK; however, it will only work with .xlsx files. I'm learning to use this SDK myself to generate .docx and .xlsx files, mainly because it's free and developed by Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact index that needs to be bold you can do something like below:

```
Using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Intertop.Excel 

Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbooks xlBooks;
Excel.Workbook xlBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlSheet;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
xlBook = xlBooks.Add("");
xlSheet = xlBook.ActiveSheet;

xlSheet.Cells[row,col].Font.Bold = true
```